# Page not rewriting in ExpressionEngine

Tags: url-rewriting, expressionengine

I recently just launched an ExpressionEngine site and one of the last steps I take is removing index.php from the URL. In the case of this site, the default template group is called "site". Long story short, after removing index.php from the URL, all pages continue to work great with the exception of my contact page, which also lives in the "site" template group. Going to http://example.com/contact/ gives me a 404 while going to http://example.com/site/contact produces the desired result. In past ExpressionEngine site setups (including my own) this has never happened, so does anyone have thoughts on why this might not be working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first URL segment always maps to the template group. When there isn't a first URL segment, ExpressionEngine automatically loads the `index` template in your default template group.

Now, you're getting the 404 because you don't have a `contact` template group. You can do one of two things here:

1. Move your `site/contact` template to `contact/index`
2. Redirect `/contact` to `/site/contact` using `.htaccess` or [Detour Pro](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/detour-pro).

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest.

Comment: See LeaLea's answer below, if you set Enable Strict URLs to 'No' then your contact template can stat where it is. The documentation for Strict URLs isn't the greatest http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html#strict-urls but if you enable that make sure that you have sufficient checks in your templates to catch legitimate 404 pages

Comment: Thanks. I think in previous installs I had disabled the Strict URLs and that's why the contact page living in the default template directory worked, but it seems like a better practice for the page to be in a separate group for consistency. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 4):

Andrew, this is possibly because of Strict URLs, too. Strict URLs in the template preferences mean that the default template group (in your case, "site") no longer resolves without the need of appending it the template group name (only exception is /index).

Jesse's solution works. In the past I've used Brandon's redirect tomfoolery here:
http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/making-pt-structure

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I had disabled Strict URLs in prior installs, but as I told Jesse, it's probably good to get in the habit of keeping certain templates in their own unique group.